# Bootstrap checkbox/switch trouble

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

Trying to determine whether the checkbox is checked or not. By default it's off, but I want to be able to do something if it gets turned on and then again if it gets turned off.

using bootstrap 5.3.0 alpha

html

```
    <div class="form-check-reverse form-switch">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="test_switch">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="test_switch">test</label>
    </div>
```

js

```
document.getElementById('test_switch').addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (this.checked) {
        console.log('checked');
    else {
        console.log('not checked');
    }
});
```

It only prints not checked, never checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the javascript code like this. this will work for you.

```
let checkbox = document.getElementById("test_switch");
checkbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
 
    if (checkbox.checked) {
        console.log('checked');
    } else {
        console.log('not checked');
    }
});

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-check-reverse form-switch">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="test_switch">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="test_switch">test</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: still not working, only prints not checked

Comment: https://codepen.io/seniordev009/pen/wvxKvQW?editors=1111

Comment: Please check this link. and let me know.

Comment: I tested it exactly after I added bootstrap 5.3.0 alpha

Comment: ```if (this.checked)``` should be changed to ```if (checkbox.checked)```. And ```click``` should be changed to ```change``` in ```addEventListener``` function.